# How to Get variable from MVC View to angular Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have this MVC application mix with angular. On Menu click we access this ClientController in server side Mvc

```
Partial Public Class ClientController
Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller 

Function ClientPartial(ByVal id As Integer) As System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
    Dim student As ManagedForm(Of mmClientPartial) = utils.GetForm(Of mmClientPartial)(id)      
      Return PartialView("ClientPartial", student)
    End Function
End Class
```

Then i have this in my view ClientPartial.vbhtml

```
<div ng-controller="studentController">
{{studentId}}
</div>
```

My angular controller is

```
 var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []); mainApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope) {
$scope.studentId = "From MVC";});


enter code here
```

The problem is how can i get the `StudentId` in my angular controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-init`

```
<div ng-controller="studentController" ng-init="studentId=@Model.Id">
{{studentId}}
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that i need this studentId in the controller to load a dropdownControl `code function getcourse() {
         return datacontext.getcourse(this.studentId).then(function (data) {
          return vm.courselist = data;
         });
        }`  So i need to have this variable available to load the dropdown

Comment: Using the suggested approach is a good fit, you can then use a `watch`  to load de dropdown by observing changes on the studentId controller variable. ex: `$scope.$watch('studentId',function(newValue,oldValue) {
  if(newValue) {
 getCourse(newValue); 
  }
});`